# Last to be created First to be executed with fork in C

Tags: c, process, fork, waitpid

Last created First finished. My teacher said "Modify the code to processes finish in reverse order".
I just started with the exercise. I don't know how to implement so that the processes are executed backwards. My solution would be make a pid processes array and then use waitpid. Like this:

```
for(int i = num_processes;i>=0;i--){
      waitpid(pid_list[i],NULL)
   }
```

[Teacher´s code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asExH.png)

[Finish order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Do8O.png)

thanks for helping!

Comment: Implement what? The kernel that schedules your processes?

Comment: You can't force the processes to execute in specific order *from outside*. You have to implement these processes in a way they are synchronizing themselves with each other, or having the parent to arbitrate them. `waitpid` is not "finishing: a process, it is "reaping" it, after it finished.

Comment: I got it. But There isnt a way to make the sequence: 
-created:p1,p2,p3
-finished:p3,p2,p1

Comment: I believe the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72600886/c-processes-exercise-using-fork/72604276#72604276) can help you out!

Comment: You could integrate descending sleeps into the processes. But without more detailed information about the goal of the exercise, it's hard to answer what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My teacher said "Modify the code to processes finish in reverse order".

Comment: I pasted a photo in the description.

Comment: The loop above will loop `n + 1` times. Your teacher has a bug!

Comment: If he was talking about modifying this loop only, then he did not state the task well. As I said, `waitpid` is not changing the execution order of processes

Comment: The description code is my prototype solution. I pasted a teacher´s code in the description.

Comment: No you did not.

Comment: i have just paste it

Comment: In your teacher code, note that it is not a single parent who is creating all the processes, but every child is creating the next one. So the question linked in one of the comments above is probably applicable.

Comment: Yep, is like a column. 
Suppose that code has wait functions.

Comment: @VXGamez solution makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The question I linked has been deleted due to it being too unclear, allow me to repost the answer here! Hopefully it helps you out!

```
//This is NODE 1
int pid = fork();

if(pid == -1){         // Something went wrong
    //Handle error
}else if(pid == 0){    // This is the child process == NODE 2
    int pid2 = fork();

    if(pid2 == -1){         // Something went wrong
        //Handle error
    }else if(pid2 == 0){    // This is the child process == NODE 3            
        // Do whatever you want done on Node 3, and have it finish.
    }else{                 //This is NODE 2
        wait(NULL);        // Waits for node 3 to finish
    }
}else{                 //This is the parent process
    //You can either do waitpid like you mentioned, or simply do wait NULL and it will wait for a process to finish
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Of course if this were to go on with more nodes, I'd recommend a recursive approach since the code is exactly the same.

You mentioned the teacher showed you the code with the loop and the waitpid, the issue there is that if you want the parent to wait for all the processes, they should all hang from this same parent, instead of having a "tree-like" structure where every parent node waits for the child to finish before ending.

If you do indeed want one node to have all the children, you can do a loop where you create the forks like the one on the screenshot, exiting the loop whenever the result from the fork is a child process instead of the parent itself. Finally, waiting for all the children you created outside the loop, but only if you are the parent process. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<N_NODES ;i++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){       
        break;                      // You exit the loop so that the child doesn't create even more processes
    }       
}

if(pid != 0){
    for(int i=0; i<N_NODES ;i++){
        wait(NULL);                 //You can do wait NULL, or store the different pids when creating the fork and wait for individual pids. 
                                    // The issue here would be that you do not know which process finishes first, you can guess, but guessing is never good when programming
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you wanted and I could help! ;)